# xamarin forms shell doesn't navigate to nested view

Tags: forms, shell, xamarin, view, navigation

I have a xamarin forms project which uses the new AppShell. I have a flyout menu with some menu items. One of the menu items is called e.g. `MyComputer`. Open it up it shows a list of folders. When I click on one folder a new page opens and shows a list of folders again - and so on - like nested folders. Unfortunately when using the new `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("folder");` to open a folder within a folder page nothing happens. No navigation is executed. It seems that it is not allowed to push the same page onto the navigation stack. However this worked with the "old" navigation `myPage.Navigation.PushAsync(folderPage);`. Because the original documentation for `AppShell` contains no restrictions for nested views I think that I'm missing something.

My `AppShell.xaml`

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems" Route="app">
  <ShellContent Title="MyComputer" Route="myComputer" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MyComputerPage}"/>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Register my folder page:

`Routing.RegisterRoute("folder", typeof(FolderPage));`

Calling the folder page from `MyComputerPage` (this works):

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("folder?name=myFolder1");`

Calling folder page from `FolderPage` **(this is not working, nothing happens, no navigation executed):**

`await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("folder?name=myFolder1b");`

I want to navigate like this:

`MyComputerPage -> FolderPage -> FolderPage -> FolderPage -> ...`

Just for better understanding how does the folder structure could look like:

- myFolder1

  - myFolder1a

    - myFolder1aX
    - myFolder1aY
    - myFolder1aZ
  - myFolder1b
  - myFolder1c
- myFolder2
- myFolder3

**EDIT:**

@Junior Jiang - MSFT here you go:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a try with `Absolute routes`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#absolute-routes

Comment: You mean navigating with `//app/folderpage` ? Yes, I tried already. But anyway I don't want to route from root. The navigation stack should stay.

Comment: Okey , got it . Could you show a screenshot with FlyoutItem when running ?

Comment: @Junior Jiang - MSFT see edit

Comment: Thanks for updating. Then when clicking MyComputer , you want to navigation to which view.

Comment: I added a GIF to see navigation clearly

Comment: I have updated an answer . Thanks for relpying and marking if solved your problem in advance.

Answer (score 1):

About [Relative Route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#relative-routes) and [Passing Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data) , from shared gif and code , maybe you mistake something when using them.

> if all the routes in an application are unique, navigation can be performed by only specifying the unique route name as a relative URI:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("TargetPageName");
//such as await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myFolder1Page");
```

> Data can be passed as query parameters when performing programmatic navigation.

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"TargetPageName?DefinedKeyName={BePassedValue}");
//such as Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"myFolder1Page?name={ValueOfmyFolder1Page}");
```

To receive data, the class that represents the page being navigated to, or the class for the page's [BindingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.bindingcontext?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_BindingContext), must be decorated with a `QueryPropertyAttribute` for each query parameter:

```
[QueryProperty("Name", "name")]
public partial class myFolder1Page: ContentPage
{
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            BindingContext = FolderData.FoldePages.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == Uri.UnescapeDataString(value));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

So here your problem , first need to rename page name to fit this route method.

**eg**:

In **MyComputerPage** , when you navigate to **myFolder1** page , you can register myFolder1 page's key be **myFolder1** page.

Then if no data :

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myFolder1");
```

Pass data :

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"myFolder1?name={ValueOfmyFolder1}");
```

When this working and next page registering as same,then have entered in **myFolder1** page ，next want to navigate to **myFolder1a** page , should write as follow:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myFolder1a");//no data
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"myFolder1a?name={ValueOfmyFolder1a}");// pass data
```

Next , want to navigate to **myFolder1aX** page ,should write as follow:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("myFolder1aX");//no data
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"myFolder1aX?name={ValueOfmyFolder1aX}");//pass data
```

Comment: This is what I understand so far from the documentation. But now think of a menu tree with thousands of folders. (e.g. Windows C:\ or nested categories in a shop app or any other recursive menu). And you want to navigate from one folder to next nested folder. Of course I don't want to create a c# class (page.cs) for every folder.

Comment: @Crunch Yeah , not need to create c# class for every folder . Although I have not tried this, it is feasible, but if you want to not create a page, then the next page needs to be multiplexed to fill in new data. This will complicate the data processing of the same page. If you want to implement a file directory browsing function, it is not recommended to use the interface navigation method. It can be clicked in a listview. More reasonable.

Comment: I see, thanks. So you confirm my doubts that this is not rly possible with the new shell navigation (although it was possible with the old NavigationService). As you already said I have to handle the new data within one page without using navigation. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Crunch For simple level navigation should still be applicable, this should be better than ordinary navigation.